# What causes a partial blackout?

Tags: electrical

Last night, my neighborhood had a blackout, but for some reason, only half of the electrical circuits in my house went out. I was under the impression that there was only one main electrical feed going into a house. Can someone please explain how this works?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this post:  http://www.homekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/repair/35373/Service-Entry-Cable-caused-partial-blackout-in-my-house

> Your house is fed with two legs at 120
>   volts each.  If you look inside your 
>   breaker box, you see three big wires
>   coming in, red, black, white.  The red
>   and black are legs of 120V, the white
>   is the neutral.  Half your circuits 
>   are on one leg, half on the other.  A
>   220V is on both.   The power company 
>   lost one of the legs and so did you.

Looks like what happened to you.

Comment: That's baaad. I lost the electronics in a clothes dryer and had a couple of surge protectors literally smoke when that happened to me. I recommend when that happens to shut off your breakers until it's corrected.

Comment: @Dennis : unfortunately when I had it happen last year it was 4 days, and we had already had 2 days of outages.  So I ran the fridge, as I had power ... but you're right, anything 220V was down (stove, clothese dryer, etc)